# window.open UTF-8 Issue

Tags: javascript, unicode, internet-explorer-8, url-encoding, window.open

I have this site:

```
http://a.b/x – y
```

where the dash is non-ASCII \u2013 or %E2%80%93 in UTF-8 speak.

The following link with UTF-8 works fine:

```
<a href="http://a.b/x%20%E2%80%93%20y" target="_blank">True Link</a>
```

but scripting it with window.open() with the exact same URL gives a 404:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open( 'http://a.b/x%20%E2%80%93%20y','_blank','top=10,left=10,height=900,width=1500,resizable=yes'))">Raw JS Link</a>
```

Viewing properties on the error page to see the resulting URL I note the extended dash is replaced with: 
  â??

If I replace the extended dash, and only the extended dash with "\u2013" the link works fine:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open( 'http://a.b/x%20\u2013%20y','_blank','top=10,left=10,height=900,width=1500,resizable=yes'))">Modified JS Link</a>
```

and the resulting URL seems to have re-endocded the extended dash back to UTF-8.

With this in mind I tried to decode the UTF-8 encoding and re-encode just the space but this failed with the same error as before:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open( decodeURIComponent('http://a.b/x%20%E2%80%93%20y').split(' ').join('%20'),'_blank','top=10,left=10,height=900,width=1500,resizable=yes'))">Raw JS Link</a>
```

I suspect that window.open() is mangling the URL for some reason.

I then went on to try a bunch of different ideas and combinations of decode / encode and even dragged escpae()/unescape() back into use, but to no avail.

The reason for window.open is that I am limited to controlling just the content of the HREF attribute. In this case it's an SSRS expression in a "Go to URL" Action, which SSRS UTF-8 encodes certain characters, so that even with the split(' ') above I actually have to use split(String.fromCharCode(32)).
However I've stripped everything out into a simple HTML page which is where I am doing my analysis with.

PS: IE8, though user base is IE8+
PSS: Added missing quote.
PSS: It looks like this might be an IE8 specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://a.b/...component...
```

So here you've got multiple nested escaping contexts. You're injecting text into:

- a component of a URL (needs URL-escaping), inside
- a JavaScript string literal (needs JS-escaping), inside
- a javascript: pseudo-URL (needs URL-escaping), inside
- an HTML attribute value (needs HTML-escaping)

So the value `x – y` has to be escaped four times:

1. URL-escape to `x%20%E2%80%93%20y`
2. JS-escape to `x%20%E2%80%93%20y` (no changes this time as there are no JS-special characters in this value)
3. URL-escape to `x%2520%25E2%2580%2593%2520y`
4. HTML-escape to `x%2520%25E2%2580%2593%2520y` (no changes this time as there are no HTML-special characters in this value).

Nested syntaxes needing escaping are very, very difficult to get right. And generally you should never use `javascript:` URLs: as well as being a nightmare of multiple-escaping, they're also pretty bad for usability and accessibility.

Avoid injecting into nested code. A better pattern for links that open in a new window (if you absolutely must) is to put the real URL in the `href`, so it responds correctly to middle-click and other link affordances, and then read that href from JS, eg.:

```
<a href="http://a.b/x%20%E2%80%93%20y" onclick="window.open(this.href, ...options...); return false;"
```

(The return-false prevents the link being followed after the window is opened.) Also consider breaking the JS code out into a separate script that binds to all appropriate links automatically (eg by `class` attribute) so you don't have to have inline JavaScript in your HTML.

Comment: The issue is IE only. Firefox, Chrome, etc have no issue. The double URL encoding is an interesting point though.

Your example does work with IE, but I mentioned in the question I can only control the content of the HREF attribute. 

It would be great if I could generate [url" onclick="script] square brackets not included, but the special characters space, quote, etc would get encoded and so not work. If I could do that I could just go  [url" target="_blank] and eliminate the need for javascript all together.

I'll try the double URL encoding.

Comment: Turns out SSRS doesn't encode '%' so I was able to write a custom function that pseudo-encoded the content I needed to the %25 level and it passes through SSRS OK, and works with IE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes were misplaced on your last example, also, there's no need for  `.split(' ').join('%20')` as it will create errors.

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open( decodeURIComponent('https://www.google.pt/search?q=x%20%E2%80%93%20y'),'_blank','top=10,left=10,height=900,width=1500,resizable=yes'))">Raw JS Link</a>
```

---

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/bf2703ah/1/

Comment: Sorry. Mistype on my part when writing the question. I will fix the question.

Comment: No, your quotes were wrong on the last example, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: I have fixed that. Your example works fine in FireFox, however on the real page the quotes are correctly placed. I had already tried decodeURIComponent(...) on its own and that still gives 404. I now suspect that it is something IE8 is doing.

Comment: I don't know **"the real page"** or have IE installed... Although,I do have chrome, Firefox, opera and edge installed and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for you help then. I don't have IE8 on a machine connected to the internet. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I can't get IE8 on my internet machine but I did get IE11 and guess what... when I use your demo the search string gets changed to "x â?? y". So it's deinately an IE behaviour and it's still there.

Comment: Its common sense that IE sucks... I'm sorry for you :(